# Extract all values between double quotes from a webpage’s source code

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have saved the source code of a webpage (the option in every browser); now I want to catch everything between quotes that starts with `http://`. How can I do that?

Comment: Use the HTML Agility Pack

Comment: Are you trying to extract some particular attribute values? An HTML parser could be more useful.

Comment: actually the source code of a page may contain links, images etc.. internal link are usually present without "http" so, I'm not interested in them.. thus, everything with http, it may be an external link or an image etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex:

```
Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(html, """(http://.+?)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

For Each m As Match In mc
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1).Value)
Next
```

Sample output when `html` = the source code of this page:

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico
http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png
http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=181da36f6419
http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=0f0c93534e2b
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264292/extract-all-values-between-double-quotes-from-a-webpages-source-code
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/91d33760d2823fa7cf5c95b41a16fada?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG\
http://stackoverflow.com/users/2264365/ajakblackgoat
http://stackexchange.com
http://chat.stackoverflow.com
... etc
```

Comment: thanks brother.. it worked perfectly :D can you please tell me how to make these patterns?

Answer (score 1):

Using [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
string path = ...
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
var links =
    from e in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
    from a in e.Attributes
    where a.Value.StartsWith("http://")
    select a.Value;
```

(note that it only returns links that are in HTML attributes, not in plain text)